# Azure "Your credentials did not work"

Tags: azure, passwords, credentials

Suddenly I'm encountering the dreaded "Your credentials did not work" error connecting to my VM. I've tried several different accounts, I've made sure of the password (I use a password management tool and the password used to work fine). I tried resetting it via the management console and I also tried resetting RDP via the console. Nothing.

The only thing that changed is that I rebooted the VM once.

Any other steps I can take to troubleshoot it? Is my only option to save the VHD and create a new VM?

Answer (score 0):

you can reset you password using the steps given here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-reset-rdp/